# PDF Composed of Images of Text - How to Convert to text file?

Tags: pdf, image-processing

I have a PDF composed of many scanned pages. An example snippet of the text is shown below (do not worry about privacy, as this is a publicly available document). As you can see, it is very difficult to read.

[image: Example of PDF]

I would like to run a program that can read this PDF, determine the text, and output a file containing the text (text file, markdown, suffix-less Linux file, even another PDF that is cleaned, any will do), so that it is easier to read for myself and others. I do not care overmuch about the formatting beyond things such as properly spacing sentences.

I have tried pdftotext, but it output a file that (in a text editor) appears to just be "^L^L^L" over and over again. I tried ocrmypdf as well, but that also did not succeed (though I am not sure I used it right). Complications include the relative "dirtiness" of the images, that the text contains various typographical errors, extra spaces, and misspelled words. What other options (usable on Linux) do you suggest to extract the text from this document?

Comment: The general rule is, if a human struggles to read it, a machine won't have a hope.

Comment: @Tetsujin I suspected this was the case, alas. It seems, then, that my only recourse is to actually type it out myself - not an easy thing when the full document is over 15000 pages long (no, that is not an error in the number of zeroes, fifteen thousand is the correct number). Wish me luck - I'll need it.

Comment: Good Luck! Some smart AI might eventually be able to figure it out, but I don't think we're there yet. Maybe by the time you've finished ;)

Comment: If the doc is public, any chance you have a link? I'd be willing to try some different tools  to see how close we can get to getting a semi accurate OCR'd copy.

Comment: @Narzard Document**s**, plural - it is several volumes. You can download them from here (albeit slowly): http://www.idaillinois.org/digital/collection/intuit/search

The ones I am interested in are the ones up to "History of my Life", though I would do the others also eventually, supposing my hands didn't fall off in the process.

Comment: This is the result I got using FineReader, a paid app. Here is the first sentence: `"This dosoription of tho great war, and its following
results, is perliaps the greivtast ever written by an author, on the lino of any
fabolue war,, that sou Id ever bo intitled, with such a nae none,."` I think there are 11 deviations from the original but most are reasonably so (the typed letter 'e' is often misshapen, and the 'u' often shifts to the left) and the output is readable enough, especially after a turn through a spell-checker. No image corrections were performed upon the source beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

The output from [FreeOCR](http://www.paperfile.net/), using the older [Tesseract OCR engine v. 5.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr.mirror/), is below. This was **not** optimized by adjusting image parameters (e.g., contrast), nor by selecting a specific font (likely fixed-width was used), nor by selecting one of the training vocabulary files (or by creating a new one with words such as "Aronburg" specific to the subject) , and it doubtless would be improved with those changes.

If this is the *only* item to be processed, it would not be worth the effort to improve processing, but if you have more images, you could tweak OCR settings to get better results.

> eae lUlUlUlUllCU
>
> ' almost destroyed, and Angolinian nat
>
> INTRODUCTION?
>
> a This doscription of the great mr, and ite following oy results, is
> perhaps the grentest ever written by an author, on the line of any
> fabolus war,, that could ever be intitled, with such a nae nama,.The'
> war . lasted abot boars -nd seven onthe dn this story,, and the :
> author of this book has-taken over eleven u years in writing. out the
> long and graphic details, and has fought on fron day,’ to day, in
> order to win |.
>
> for tho christ inn sd side this long and bloody war, and though the
> christ = dans had beon threntenod with defeat, on account of a strange
> Aronburg mystery |" |
>
> which could not be solved by any one, not even mysolf, they finally
> won when thoy turned tho tide against. the eneny at the frightful
> battle of Aronburgs Rune : .
>
> Tho Aronurg uystery as voll as the murder of the Aronburg child, had
> threat a my
>
> enod the doo of the three christinn states, for the whole length of
> the great Glandco Angolinian war, and it was predicted that the
> solving of the Aronburg wyste ry or for the ravenge of her’
> assassins,‘ was the only hope — Tor any chance of the christian nation
> winning the wire Abbieannia managed to crush Glondelinin herself,
> after , Claverinia had beon ruined, and ‘
>
> Gon wlnost wiped out in hor anaiose

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is far from the only item to be processed - this about 1/3 of a page, of which there are about 15000 in total (not a typo). Making those optimizations would thus be well worth it. I will look into this posthaste.

Comment: @Benyamin, good luck... and note that the OCR engine installed along with FreeOCR may not be latest, so download a newer Tesseract engine, as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is for a single person likely to take a minimum four years and seven moths, or with luck only eleven u years. The best solution is see if crowd ghost writing this "Classic" is possible (or pester Googles Charity Branch) but you need to have ground rules as to should the speeling mistooks be retained?

[image]

Only earlier pages are Typewritten and many later ones are monochrome thus would need to be scanned again in greyscale to have a chance of OCR or Human transcription.
[image]

Comment: Indeed, ground rules would be needed. This was actually something that occurred to me as I began to type it myself - it quickly became clear that a group would be the only reasonable way. I kept waffling on what to do with typos - if they were single extra letters, I often ignored them, but misspellings I was adding [sic] at the end of them, so as to differentiate from cases where my typing was in error. Either way, I have a very odd and ridiculous interest in making this readable, so I'm seriously considering it. (Rescanning would require help from a museum, so probably off the table.)

Comment: Challenging companies to do the better job OCRing this work did not occur to me as a possible solution. I confess that I was not anticipating things to escalate like this.

Comment: At the very least, I think the internet archive should host the documents, and I am seriously considering asking if I can post them there. The documents are by and large *readable* in the current form, at least to someone with good eyesight and fluent in English such as myself. (If I had English as a second language or eyesight problems, I would probably have more trouble.) Ensuring they are archived elsewhere, even in this form, would be good in my opinion - but we digress.